# nodejs socket.io : How to reconnect socker after socket.disconnect() is called?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

How can I connect to socket again after I call disconnect

Here is the client source code

```
socket = io.connect('http://myServer:1339'); // connect socket
socket.disconnect(); // disconnect socket
socket = io.connect('http://myServer:1339'); // does not connect socket again !
```

Why do I call disconnect ?

Because I have myServer and myServer2 servers. If I switch between myserver and myserver2, I got many sockets connections (like adding)

Any idea on how to clearly close a socket and open a new one ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call io.connect a second time.

To reconnect, you should use

```
socket.socket.connect()
```